# Elastic search query according to MySQL Group by clause

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch I want to write a query for getting unique record on the basis of query and group:

```
SELECT * from users where name='%john%', age='21', location='New York' group by name
```

Could you please let me know how to write the query in elasticsearch with query.

Answer (score 0):

It would go something like this. You need a filtered query with a [`query_string`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) in the query part to match `*john*` and then two filters in the `filter` part to match the `age` and the `location`. Finally, the grouping is achieved using a [`terms`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) aggregation.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query": {
      "query_string": {
        "query": "*john*",
        "default_field": "name"
      }
    },
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "age": 21
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "location": "New York"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name"
      }
    }
  }
}
```